# Syntax for using an array with IN as parameter

Tags: php, cypher

Probably a no-brainer but google didn't help me the last 30 minutes so maybe someone has done this already and can nudge me to the right syntax;

I have a typical php-array like

```
$idArray = array(7) { [0]=> string(13) "55b753312986c" [1]=> string(13) "55b751f83d9f3" [2]=> string(13) "55b752b6ab7fd" [3]=> string(13) "55b7531fbb5ad" [4]=> string(13) "55b75346baae8" [5]=> string(13) "55b752c9aea0a" [6]=> string(13) "55b753417d577" }
```

I want to ask in the query if a property is in this array. I tried to put this into a parameter like

```
$queryParam = array("selectedID" => $idArray);
```

Next I wanted to query my DB like

```
MATCH (u:User) --> (n:Node)
WHERE u.id IN {selectedID}
RETURN u
```

Somehow the syntax is incorrect and I would appreciate a hint how to type the query accurately. Thanks very much.

Comment: just `implode` the array like this: `$idString = implode(',', $idArray)` and pass to `mysql` query like `WHERE u.id IN ($idString)`

Comment: The syntax seems ok (by the looks of it). Are you getting any kind of error message back from the server?

Comment: Hi all, thanks. Implode was a first move but I had problems with adding the  required " - so I solved this with a string and a loop  - that helped. Though I wasnt able to pass the string by parameters (always got Type Mismatch or literal number or invalid input errors depending on how I used ", [ and , ) so I gave in now and add the sting directly into the query which works. Still I am wondering how I would pass it via parameter as this seems better.